# Extract digits from string with consecutive digit characters

Tags: python, string, extract

I cannot use Regular Expressions or library :(. I need to extract all digits from an alphanumeric string. Each consecutive sequence of digits (we can call "temperature") is precluded by a (+, -, or *) and will be considered as a single number (all are integers, no float). There are other non digit characters in the string that can be ignored. I need to extract each "temperature" into a data structure.

Example String "BARN*21+77-48CDAIRY*87+56-12"  yields [21, 77, 48, 87, 56, 12]

The data string can be many many magnitudes larger.

All solutions I can find assume there is only 1 sequence of digits (temperature) in the string or that the (temperatures) are separated by a space/delimiter. I was able to get working by iterating through string and adding a space before and after each digit sequence and then using split but that feels like cheating. I wonder if you professionals distort data for a happy solution??

incoming data "BARN*21+77-48CDAIRY*87+56-12"
temp is what I change data to

```
temp = "BARN* 21 + 77 - 48 DAIRY* 87 + 56 - 12"
result = [int(i)
for i in temp.split()
    if i.isdigit()]
    print("The result ", result)
```

The result  [21, 77, 48, 87, 56, 12]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version which does not use regular expressions:

```py
inp = "BARN21+77-48CDAIRY87+56-12"
inp = ''.join(' ' if not ch.isdigit() else ch for ch in inp).strip()
nums = inp.split()
print(nums)  # ['21', '77', '48', '87', '56', '12']
```

If regex be available for you, we can use `re.findall` with the regex pattern `\d+`:

```py
inp = "BARN21+77-48CDAIRY87+56-12"
nums = re.findall(r'\d+', inp)
print(nums)  # ['21', '77', '48', '87', '56', '12']
```

Comment: OP says can't use regular expressions.

Comment: @nicomp I have added an option which does not use regular expressions.  Of course, in practice most devs would use regex here.

Comment: Wow, thank you Tim! You completed in way less time than it took me to write the question. I will review RegEx solution as well, maybe I can use in the future. Now I will try to understand the code :)